# What is the difference between $location.path(redirecturl) and $location.url(redirecturl)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am talking about the setter methods for both and not the getter method

For me $location.url <strike>doesnt always</strike> takes a while to redirect so i was thinking of using $location.path but I wanted to know the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in the getter of the `$location.url()` and the `$location.path()`

The url() getter returns path, search and hash in the form of `/path?search=a&b=c#hash` , while as `path()` will only return `/path`.

In terms of redirection, if it is only to a path, then yes I would use

```
$location.path(redirectpath).
```

You can read more about at [`$location` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Answer (score 4):

Basically, `path` returns only the path but `url` also returns possible search or other parameters.

Check out the examples from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location):

**$location.path**:

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var path = $location.path();
// => "/some/path"
```

**$location.url**:

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var url = $location.url();
// => "/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"
```

Comment: Please check my clarification

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Would you consider deleting it because it makes it harder to find a real answer?

Answer (score 0):

`path` is only part of `url` that doesn't include `search` and `hash`

See examples in [$location docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)